# How do I color the stippled underline in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, tmlanguage

I have a plugin using the [add_regions](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) command to draw underlines for certain regions.

I also have a custom `tmLanguage` and `tmTheme`, so I can control font style/foreground color etc. for scopes I have set.

Now, I'm trying to get my underlines to be a specific color (and not the default white-ish ST3 color)... I know this is possible because the spellcheck in ST3 has a red squiggly underline.

I've poked at changing the scope/settings/keys etc. in my tmTheme and my plugin's add_regions command, but nothing seems to stick.

Any direction would be very helpful!

Comment: using a different scope works for me to change the color of the underline - select some text and type this in the console to see the effect `view.add_regions('test', [view.sel()[0]], 'entity.name.tag', '', sublime.DRAW_STIPPLED_UNDERLINE | sublime.DRAW_NO_FILL | sublime.DRAW_NO_OUTLINE)` and then change `entity.name.tag` to `comment` or `string` etc.

Comment: @KeithHall Interesting... I tested it and it seems to work. So I have to use an entirely different scope to source the color... I'll test it some more and report back :)

Comment: @KeithHall - Working like a charm!!! Thank you! Feel free to write an answer and I'll accept (or I can write the answer, if you don't care for the karma).

Comment: feel free to write the answer yourself - you would benefit more from the rep more than me I think :)

Comment: @KeithHall - done!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set up a dummy scope in your `tmTheme` file with the `foreground` setting valued to the color you want your underline to be. Then pass in that scope name to the `add_regions` function call.

Example for yellow underline...

In the `tmTheme` file:

```xml
...
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Yellow Underline</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>underline.yellow.text</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#FFFF00</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
...
```

In your plugin:

```py
# ...
# set regions variable above
view.add_regions('key', regions, 'underline.yellow.text', '', sublime.DRAW_STIPPLED_UNDERLINE | sublime.DRAW_NO_FILL | sublime.DRAW_NO_OUTLINE)
# ...
```

Ta-da! You should have yellow underlines now :)